# Dynamometer - ask for improvement suggestions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

Please.

[image: Dynamometer]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape,every node/.style={scale=1.0}]

%argola
\definecolor{meu_cinzento}{RGB}{116, 123, 129}
\tkzDefPoint(02,25){O1}
\tkzDefPoint(02,23){O2}
\tkzDefPoint(02,20){O3}
\tkzDrawArc[R,line width = 6pt,color=meu_cinzento](O1,2)(0,360)
\tkzDrawSegment[line width = 3pt,color=meu_cinzento](O2,O3)

%gancho
\definecolor{meu_cinzento}{RGB}{116, 123, 129}
\tkzDefPoint(02,5){O1}
\tkzDefPoint(02,7){O2}
\tkzDefPoint(02,9){O3}
\tkzDrawArc[R,line width = 6pt,color=meu_cinzento](O1,2)(90,360)
\tkzDrawSegment[line width = 6pt,color=meu_cinzento](O2,O3)

%espelho do dinamómetro
\definecolor{meu_cinzento}{RGB}{175, 191, 196}
\tkzDefPoint(02,10){O}
\tkzDrawCircle[R,meu_cinzento!20,fill=meu_cinzento,opacity=1](O,2)
\tkzDrawArc[R,line width = 3pt,color=black](O,2)(180,0)
\tkzDefPoint(02,20){O}
\tkzDrawCircle[R,meu_cinzento!20,fill=meu_cinzento,opacity=1](O,2)
\tkzDrawArc[R,line width = 3pt,color=black](O,2)(0,180)
\tkzDefPoint(00,10){P1}
\tkzDefPoint(00,20){P2}
\tkzDefPoint(04,20){P3}
\tkzDefPoint(04,10){P4}
\tkzDrawPolygon[fill=meu_cinzento!20,color=meu_cinzento](P1,P2,P3,P4)
\tkzDrawSegment[line width = 3pt,color=black](P1,P2)
\tkzDrawSegment[line width = 3pt,color=black](P3,P4)

%ranhura do ponteiro
\tkzDefPoint(02,10){P1}
\tkzDefPoint(02,20){P2}
\tkzDrawSegment[line width = 3pt,color=black](P1,P2)

%escala
\foreach \i in {0,...,20}{%
    \tkzDefPoint(1.5,{10+0.5*\i}){O\i}}
\foreach \i in {0,...,20}{%
    \tkzDefPoint(2.5,{10+0.5*\i}){P\i}}
\foreach \i in {0,...,20}{%
    \tkzDrawSegment[line width = 0.5pt,color=black](O\i,P\i)}

%ponteiro
\tkzDrawSegment[line width = 5pt,color=red](O5,P5)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `\definecolor` multiple times if you don't re-define the color. Also, you don't need to repeat the same `\foreach` expression three times. Apart from that, I would probably just use plain `tikz` to draw this ... But: what exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't like the way the segments join each other

Comment: I agree with @JasperHabicht you need to use `tikz-pgf` and not `tkz-euclide`.

Answer (score 7):

There may be a way to connect `tkz-euclide` macros so that they join nicely (which I am not aware of), or you could use the `line cap` option.

But, I think it is much easier to draw this with plain `tikz` and not load `tkz-euclide`. The code would be a lot shorter then:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{meu_cinzento-1}{RGB}{116, 123, 129}
\definecolor{meu_cinzento-2}{RGB}{175, 191, 196}

%argola
\draw[line width=6pt, meu_cinzento-1] (2,25) circle (2);
\draw[line width=3pt, meu_cinzento-1] (2,23) -- ++(0,-3);

%gancho
\draw[line width=6pt, meu_cinzento-1] (2,9) -- ++(0,-2) arc (90:360:2);

%espelho do dinamómetro
\draw[line width=3pt, fill=meu_cinzento-2] (4,20) arc (0:180:2) -- ++(0,-10) arc (180:360:2) -- cycle; 

%ranhura do ponteiro
\draw[line width=3pt] (2,20) -- ++(0,-10); 

%escala (com ponteiro)
\foreach \i in {0,...,20}{
    \ifnum\i=5
        \draw[line width=5pt, red] 
    \else
        \draw[line width=0.5pt] 
    \fi
        (1.5,{10+0.5*\i}) -- ++(1,0);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some additional remarks:

- You don't need to define a color multiple times, and I would suggest that you name different colors differently.
- You can include more than just one drawing command in a `\foreach` macro. So, there is no need to repeat the very same `\foreach` definition multiple times here.

Comment: Thank you all. I've found that my classes adapt better to TKZ, with a smaller set of commands, than to TikZ-pgf. You're right, but I think I should go for the simpler solution and hope that they'll then evolve into a more labor-intensive solution, from their point of view.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add : `line cap=round,line join=round` and it is better to use `TikZ`, `tkz-euclide` is for euclidean geometry.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape,every node/.style={scale=1.0},line cap=round,line join=round]

%argola
\definecolor{meu_cinzento}{RGB}{116, 123, 129}
\tkzDefPoint(02,25){O1}
\tkzDefPoint(02,23){O2}
\tkzDefPoint(02,20){O3}
\tkzDrawArc[R,line width = 6pt,color=meu_cinzento](O1,2)(0,360)
\tkzDrawSegment[line width = 3pt,color=meu_cinzento](O2,O3)

%gancho
\tkzDefPoint(02,5){O1}
\tkzDefPoint(02,7){O2}
\tkzDefPoint(02,9){O3}
\tkzDrawArc[R,line width = 6pt,color=meu_cinzento](O1,2)(90,360)
\tkzDrawSegment[line width = 6pt,color=meu_cinzento](O2,O3)

%espelho do dinamómetro
\definecolor{meu_cinzento}{RGB}{175, 191, 196}
\tkzDefPoint(02,10){O}
\tkzDrawCircle[R,meu_cinzento!20,fill=meu_cinzento,opacity=1](O,2)
\tkzDrawArc[R,line width = 3pt,color=black](O,2)(180,0)
\tkzDefPoint(02,20){O}
\tkzDrawCircle[R,meu_cinzento!20,fill=meu_cinzento,opacity=1](O,2)
\tkzDrawArc[R,line width = 3pt,color=black](O,2)(0,180)
\tkzDefPoint(00,10){P1}
\tkzDefPoint(00,20){P2}
\tkzDefPoint(04,20){P3}
\tkzDefPoint(04,10){P4}
\tkzDrawPolygon[fill=meu_cinzento!20,color=meu_cinzento](P1,P2,P3,P4)
\tkzDrawSegments[line width = 3pt,color=black](P1,P2 P3,P4)

%ranhura do ponteiro
\tkzDefPoint(02,10){P1}
\tkzDefPoint(02,20){P2}
\tkzDrawSegment[line width = 3pt,color=black](P1,P2)

%escala
\foreach \i in {0,...,20}{%
    \tkzDefPoint(1.5,{10+0.5*\i}){O\i}
    \tkzDefPoint(2.5,{10+0.5*\i}){P\i}
    \tkzDrawSegment[line width = 0.5pt,color=black](O\i,P\i) }

%ponteiro
\tkzDrawSegment[line width = 5pt,color=red](O5,P5)

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this (minimalist):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,calc}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw[gray,line width=12pt] (0,0) arc (180:0:2);
        \filldraw[brown] (-1,0) rectangle (5,-22);
            \node[white] at (2.1,-.5) (a) {\bfseries \large Range: 0-18.5 kg};
        \draw[cyan,line width=20pt,centered] (2.1,-1)--(2.1,-21);
        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,18}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\h{-2-\i};
            \pgfmathsetmacro\j{-2.5-\i};
            \pgfmathsetmacro\k{.5+\i};
            \draw[white,line width=3pt] (1.6,\h)--(1.2,\h) node[left] (\i) {\bfseries \large $\i$};
            \draw[white,line width=3pt] (2.6,\j)--(3.0,\j) node[right] (\i) {\bfseries \large $\k$};
        }
        \draw[red,line width=3] (1.5,-2)--(2.7,-2);
        \draw[gray,line width=12pt] (2.1,-22)--(2.1,-23) arc (90:360:2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]